# How to list the available Windows domains from a java application?

Tags: java, active-directory, authentication

I have to authorise users using its Windows account in a web application.
I use LDAP to validate with the Active Directory if the user/pwd in a specific domain is correct, but I need a list of the available domains because the users can be from differents domains. I try a DNS SRV query to list the ldap servers ( _ldap._tcp ) but I don't get the ssl ldap Active Directory servers.
The host app is in a Unix machine, not Windows.

Comment: Authorizate? You mean Authorise surely?

Comment: @Gary Rowe: Yes, authorise. Sorry my poor english

Comment: I was thinking in something like conecting anonymously to the Active Directory LDAP & searching for this info somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure that this will work since I don't have access to the necessary libraries, but it seems that you'll need to do something like this:

Get hold of the ADSI JARs. This is the really tricky bit. [Perhaps this article can help](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/other_examples/Creating_an_NT_User_via_ADSI_from_Java.htm) with the initial configuration or you [can go with J++ here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746421%28VS.85%29.aspx), or maybe [this one from Isocra consulting](http://www.isocra.com/2005/05/adsi-from-java/). If you're hosting your application on Linux and calling into a Windows based AD server, then see section 3 of the first article. In essence you'll be creating some Java proxies onto the ADSI COM object and then calling through them into a remote AD server.

Once that's configured, then this might just do it

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      // The key is not to include any domain in your call apparently
      Set domains = (Set) ADsGetObject("WinNT:", IADs.iid);
      for (PropertyCache domain: domains) {
        System.out.println(domain.getName());
      }
  }

  /**
   * @dll.import("activeds", ole)
   */
  private static native IUnknown ADsGetObject(String path, _Guid riid);

}
```

Rather than being a complete answer, this may just get you started in the right direction. However, it does look like it could be very difficult to get working.

[This SO answer may also help (it's in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263906/inferring-ldap-address-from-nt-domain-name)

Comment: This solution seems to use Windows APIs with JNI. The app is hosted in a Unix machine.

Comment: thanks. It's similar to this link: http://itchanged.com/FindingAllDomainsInAnActiveDirectoryForest.html in Visual .net but still can't do it whith java & my env. setup yet.